# How reference an image file location in Flask? (beginner)

Tags: flask, jinja2

A Flask route passes a variable called imgloc to the Jinja template of the full path to an image file on the server. How do I refer to this in an image tag in HTML? The code:

```
<img src="{{url_for(filename=imgloc)}}">
```

does not work. Printing out the variable `imgloc` works fine , so it is being correctly passed to the template. In essence:

```
<img src="{{WHAT_GOES_IN_HERE}}">
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/cat.png') }}">`

It will be pointed to the `/path/to/project/static/img/cat.png`

A simple google search would have solved the issue, they have everything in docs.

Docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/